# Help finding linear constraint - LP

Tags: linear-programming, constraint, scheduling

I have the following question. I have two variables $w_{nds}$ and $m_{nd}$. The first variable indicates whether a nurse $n$ works shift $s$ on day $d$. The second one indicates the motivation of nurse $n$ on day $d$. How can I link both and create a new variable $moti_{nds}$ that combines both information. So the new variable should capture the motivation for each nurse for each shift each day. The value of $moti$ for a given shift should be $\ge 0$ only if the nurse works this shift. For example, if she works all shifts in a day then $moti_{1ds}=1 ~\forall s\in S$ should hold. My suggestion would be:

$\begin{align}
&moti_{nds}=w_{nds}\cdot m_{nd}~~~~\forall n\in N, d\in D, s\in S
\end{align}$

Would this be a linear formulation? I would be because, yes, you multiply a variable with two indices by one over three. Is this possible?

Comment: What is really the difference between $w_{nds}$ and $moti_{nds}$?

Answer (score 1):

To linearize product of two variables with $moti_{nds}$ & $ m_{nd}$ are binary
$ w_{nds}+ m_{nd} \le moti_{nds}+1$

$moti_{nds}\le m_{nd}$
$moti_{nds}\le w_{nds} $

You can sum $w$ and moti over shift $s$ for last 2 constraints for nurse $n$ works  on a given day $d$.

$\sum_s moti_{nds}\le m_{nd}$
$\sum_s moti_{nds}\le  \sum_s w_{nds} \le S\sum_s moti_{nds}$

In case $m_{n,d}$ is continuous variable in domain $[L,U]$ then

$L w_{nds} \le \sum_s moti_{nds} \le Uw_{nds}$

$m_{nd}+L(1-w_{nds}) \le \sum_s moti_{nds} \le m_{nd}+U(1-w_{nds})$

Comment: Thanks. Would a linearization be necessary if $m_{nd}\in \left[  0,1\right]$?

Comment: @nflgreaternba most modern solvers can handle product of 2 variables (whether binary or continuous). Still updated my answer just in case $ m_{ds}$ is continuous to linearize. Linearization of product of 2 variables may make the model faster.